# General items in Non-Persian font using the XePersian package?

Tags: xepersian

Working on a book I first run into the page numbering problem that is discussed elsewhere, but I guess the problem is more general. When I try the following code, I get a Persian date in the footer and I get Persian page numbers. I really tried a lot, including the redefinition of `\pagemark` from the `scrpage2` package. But I think this should not be necessary for users of this package. When I use `\begin{latin}` I expect everything inside there to behave latin. This includes date expressions, page numbers, question marks for missing citations, and so on.

The package is great and I would like to use it. Maybe there is a way to use parts of it to get the type setting of single sentences done (that's what I need, I am a linguist) and leave out the things that effect the whole document.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{scrpage2}\ohead{\lr{\headmark}}\ihead{\pagemark}\cfoot{}\ofoot[]{\lr{Draft of \today}}

\usepackage{xepersian}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\lr{\arabic{page}}}{\arabic{page}}}\let\cite=\latincite

\settextfont{XB Niloofar} 

%\def\pagemark{{\lr{\pnumfont\thepage}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{latin}


\frontmatter

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chapter*{Preface}


We thank for discussion.

\newpage

We thank the \LaTeX{} developers for support.

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter Title}

Some text.

\newpage

Even more text.

\appendix


\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, found the way to get Persian sentences without buying the whole package: \documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{Yas}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{XB Niloofar}

\usepackage{bidi}


\begin{document}
This is typeset by \textsf{bidi} package, \bidiversion, \bididate.

\RL{او مرد را دوست داشت.}
\end{document}

Comment: Make a bug report in https://github.com/vafa/xepersian/issues but I do not promise updating xepersian package unless there is some donations to the project

Comment: @StefanMüller Can you add a self-answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the way to get Persian sentences without buying the whole package. Use xelatex with the following:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}    
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{XB Niloofar} 
\usepackage{bidi} 

\begin{document} 
This is typeset by \textsf{bidi} package, \bidiversion, \bididate. 

\RL{او مرد را دوست داشت.} 
\end{document}
```